# What did Linus Torvalds mean by his quotation about portability?

Tags: portability, quotations

In [a debate with Andrew Tanenbaum](http://oreilly.com/catalog/opensources/book/appa.html) over microkernel vs. monolithic operating system architecture, [Linus Torvalds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linus_Torvalds) said,

> Portability is for people who cannot write new programs.

What did he mean by that?

Comment: Be careful what you read about when pulling out these "debates" (flamewars) from the "old" days.  Consider that because Linux was very dear to Linus's heart there was likely a lot of emotion surging during these discussions.  Therefore you're likely to come across many statements being made just to be cheeky or to piss someone off.

Comment: This type of question is now being [discussed on our meta-discussion site](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/2645/8).

Comment: recommended reading: **[Discuss this ${blog}](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6417/discuss-this-blog)**

Answer (score 81, accepted):

As Linus writes in the debate, it's with tongue in cheek (i.e. not to be taken too seriously).

Then, he goes on to explain that while portability is good thing, it's also a trade-off; unportable code can be much simpler. That is, instead of making the code perfectly portable, just make it simple and *portable enough* ("adhere to a portable API"), and then if it needs to be ported, rewrite it as needed. Making code perfectly portable can also seen as a form of premature optimization - often more harm than good.

Of course that's not possible if you can't write new programs and have to stick with the original one :)

Comment: Agreed on premature optimization.

Comment: +1 Linus is known for his tongue in cheek humour but some take what he says way too seriously.

Answer (score 12):

I think it means that each program should be written specifically for the hardware and operating system it runs on.

I think what he's driving as is that general purpose code that can run on several platforms is less efficient or more error prone than code written specifically for and tailored to one platform. It does, however, mean that when you develop like this you have to maintain several different code lines.

Comment: i think this is **exactly** what he meant

Answer (score 8):

Back when Linux was first written, it used features available only on the i386 CPU, which was fairly new and expensive at the time.

> That is exactly what linux does: it
>   just uses a bigger subset of the 386
>   features than other kernels seem to
>   do.  Of course this makes the kernel
>   proper unportable, but it also makes
>   for a /much/ simpler design.  An
>   acceptable trade-off, and one that
>   made linux possible in the first
>   place.

As we went into the 21st century, the features that made the i386 unique became totally mainstream, allowing Linux to become very portable.

Comment: "...became totally mainstream, allowing Linux to become very portable," and proved that portability of Linux, at that point in time, would have been premature optimization.

Comment: @Roger: I can't really agree. Those features have become mainstream -- but in the time since, CPUs have added more features, many of which Linux either ignores completely, uses only minimally, or has had to be massively (and painfully) rewritten to use even reasonably well. At the same time, Linus does have at least some point: something that works *reasonably* well now (even non-portably) beats something that gets talked about for years but never finished (e.g., GNU HURD).

Comment: @Jerry - sounds like research projects at a place I used to work: "You should give up now. What I'm working on will render all you do obsolete". That was 20 years ago. Still haven't seen that whiz-bang new stuff leave the research lab.

Comment: @Roger, portability is not an optimization.

Answer (score 6):

As someone who's done a lot of Java, and experienced the "write once, debug everywhere" phenomenon on a weekly basis for years, I can fully relate to this.

And Java is probably a mild example. I can't even begin to imagine what people go through who try to while a portable code base in a language/toolkit which wasn't even designed to be portable in and of itself.

Right now at work, we are investigating the idea of writing a lite version of one of our products for mobile devices. I've done some research on how to do a portable version of it for both J2ME and Android - that tries to share as much of the codebase as possible (obviously can't be fully "portable" per se, but it's a similar philosophy). It's a nightmare.

So yeah, sometimes it really is good to be able to think (and do) in terms of using the given tools for the given job. ie Freely developing against one, single, monolithic platform/enviroment. And just writing separate, clean versions for each.

Answer (score 5):

Although some people view/treat portability, following standards, etc., as morally superior, or something on that order, what it really boils down to is economics.

Writing portable code has a cost in terms of effort to make the code portable, and (often) foregoing some features that aren't available on all targets.

Non-portable code has a cost in terms of effort to port the code when/if you care about a new architecture, and (often) foregoing some features that aren't (or weren't) available on the original target.

The big qualifier there is "when/if you care about a new architecture". Writing portable code requires effort up-front in the *hope* of an eventual payoff of being able to use that code on new/different architectures with little or no effort. Non-portable code lets you delay that investment in porting until you're (at least reasonably) sure you really need to port to some particular target.

If you're sure up-front that you're going to port to a lot of targets, it's usually worthwhile to invest up-front in minimizing long-term porting costs. If you're less certain about how much (or even if) you'll need to port the code, writing non-portable code lets minimize the up-front cost, delaying or possibly even completely avoiding the cost of making the code portable.

I think it's also worth noting that I've spoken of "portable" and "non-portable" as if there was a clear-cut division between the two. In reality, that's not true -- portability is a continuum, running from thoroughly non-portable (e.g., assembly code) to extremely portable (e.g., Info-zip), and everywhere in between.

Answer (score 4):

Tanenbaum makes the point that much of Linux is written in a non-modular way to leverage the 386 CPU, state of the art at the time, instead of making the CPU interaction be a component, and thus very easily swappable. Tanenbaum essentially believes that the fact that the Kernel is so monolithic and tied to 386 CPU makes it very difficult to,

- Port Linux itself to another CPU platform (Obviously incorrect, AMD64, PowerPC, etc)
- Port Programs written for linux x86 to another CPU architecture (also incorrect)

The linux camp makes several points, among which:

- Linux offers multithreaded filesystem as part of the design
- Microkernel, while interesting and intuitive are not very performant
- The portable API adherence makes the portability issue more or a niggle as opposed to a blocker.

Comment: Now hold on... at the time of this debate, portability was a much bigger concern. AMD64 and PPC came many years.

Comment: You are absolutely right - however, others, including Linus pointed out that it wasn't as much of a concern as Tanenbaum seemed to think

Comment: Microkernels don't perform well?  That would come as a shock to those of us who've used them.

Comment: *I* don't think that microkernels don't work well - I use Mach (OsX) and it works great. Linus, however, did mention it.

Answer (score 3):

**If you're want to write portable code, you have to write portable code.**

What do I mean by that?

The design must reflect the purpose. If the language is C, for instance, design it so that the minimum number of lines of code need to change in order for it to work. This would often mean separating the display from the computation, which is a good design philosophy anyway (MVC). Most C code can be compiled anywhere, provided you have access to a good compiler. Leverage that and write as much as you can to be generic.

BTW, this answer will only apply for applications. OS and embedded are another animal entirely.

Answer (score 2):

Interpret this statement "literally" the way it is.

In another of Linus's quotes he said : "C++ is trying to solve all the wrong Problems. The things C++ *solves* are trivial things, almost purely syntactic extensions to C rather than fixing some true deep problem".

Also in his biography, "Just For Fun" linus while quoting about microkernels said that for a problem with complexity 'n' if you divide the problem in '1/n' unique parts.. then the total complexity of developing such a system would be 'n!' this itself is a factor enough not to attempt such a thing, and extracting efficiency from such a complex system would be very difficult.

Answer (score 2):

You have to take into account the fact that during those debates, Linux was very new and was largely a 386 only OS.  I think if you asked Linus today, he would have a different opinion.  Maybe not quite as extreme as Tannenbaums, but he will likely give hime a nod and say that he was right about some things.

Linus and the other kernel developers went through a lot of pain to make Linux portable, but then again, Linux may never have existed if Linus had had to make it portable to begin with.

Answer (score 2):

It means that people who can write good programs don't need things to be portable, because they can work from scratch.

It is less gifted programmers who want to "import" other programs (portability) to the current one.